# How do I use events in my ChromeWorker?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When I try to

```
var { on, once, off, emit } = require('resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core');
```

inside my worker.js, I get an error that

```
TypeError: The argument to require() must be a string uri, got ../core/namespace
```

however, the same call works fine in my index.js. Are events not accessible from workers?

**Update.** I think this is probably a problem inside core.js as there is an sdk/core/namespace per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/core_namespace, sadly require ('sdk/event/core') does not do it.

Comment: Hm I'm not sure, it might be that `require` you are using is a different kind of `require`. I think the SDK expects you to use  a non-resource path. So like `require('event/core')` should probably be all you need

Comment: It seems that the ChromeWorker imported ```require``` is a different kind indeed. However, it requires you to use a string uri. The example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/ChromeWorkers/Chrome_Worker_Modules where you require("resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_shared_allthreads.jsm"); works. I think inside sdk/event/core it tells you to load ../core/namespace and that is how this new require fails.

Comment: I just want 'it just works (TM)'

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see what's going on here. You can't use thse SDK modules or other XPCOM componeents in ChromeWorker. These are the things available to workers -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers#workerscope

Outside of that, you'll have to handle everything yourself. Workers are very light weight, very bare.

Comment: that doesn't explain why you can require("resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_shared_allthreads.jsm") in the example

Comment: That module (`osfile` and dependencies) uses only ctypes. So it is safe to import into workers.